# Вылетает приложение CriminalIntent при нажатии кнопки сделать фотографию

Tags: android, android-intent

изучаю андроид по книге Android. Программирование для профессионалов. 4-е издание. На главе 16 (интенты при работе с камерой) столкнулся с проблемой, как только я нажимаю кнопку(кнопка вызывает камеру и сохраняет фото на устройстве) сделать фото приложение вылетает с такой вот ошибкой

msg: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE flg=0x3 clip={text/uri-list {...}} (has extras) }

Камера есть,проверяю на физическом устройстве, SD карты нет разве что.Поясните пожалуйста новичку в чём здесь проблема.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49435522/error-no-activity-found-to-handle-intent-act-android-media-action-image-capture